Probabilistic proof of $\varphi(n) = n\prod_{p \mid n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)$
In these video lectures Ram Murty gives a, I think, very intuitive to remember probabilistic proof of the following equality of the Euler $\varphi$ function:
$$ \varphi(n) = n\prod_{p \mid n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) $$
Proof: $$\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n}$$ equals to the probability that a number is coprime with $n$ (ocurrences over total cases).
On the other hand a number is coprime with $n$ if it doesn't divide any of the prime divisors of $n$, the probability of $k \nmid p$ with $p \mid n$ is $$\dfrac{p-1}{p}$$ so because these are independent and we want the number to not divide any of the primes that divide $n$ we can multiply them to get the desired product.
My issue: Although I understand the point of this proof I don't see how it is actually true, I know you can talk about the probability $\dfrac{p-1}{p}$ in the limit as a density but not for actual fixed numbers, so there's something I'm probably missing in my definitions or knowledge.
Any help or hints to understand this are appreciated. Thanks.

I'd say this was a heuristic proof; at least, it's not obviously complete as it stands.  You need to argue that being prime to $p_1,p_2$ for distinct primes are independent events.  That seems more subtle than the thing we are trying to prove (which, of course, follows immediately from multiplicativity).

Your concern is about choosing a random element from an infinite set, but here the random element is from the finite set ${1,\dots,n}$, so the uniform distribution is well-defined.

Say $p,q$ are distinct primes.  If, say, $n$ is a multiple of $pq$ then  you can write out the exact counts in question and confirm the independence directly.  But, again, for general $n$ you need to argue more to get what you want.  I'd recommend treating the argument as heuristic only.

@Karl But how can it be well defined if its a finite set, for example $n = p+1$ with $p$ prime the probability that a number doesn't divide $p$ in the set is not $(p-1)/p$ its $p/(p+1)$.

You are missing the point.  The product is taken over the primes dividing $n$.  Thus, if $p,q$ are distinct primes dividing $n$, you know that $n$ is a multiple of $pq$.  That means you can just do the count explicitly.  Don't think about general $n$...the claim isn't true as stated in general (consider, say, $n=4$ with $(p,q)=(2,3)$).  Of course, this only handles two prime factors of $n$.

We are considering a fixed $n$ and a prime $p$ that divides $n$. Under these conditions, if you pick a random number $k\in{1,\dots,n}$, then the probability that $p|k$ is exactly $1/p$. The harder part, as lulu says, is to justify that the events are independent for different prime divisors of $n$.

@lulu ok I think I've got it now, thank you.

@lulu Btw you can post the answer if you like, if not I'll try to write it myself later.

There is no need to discuss natural density, and the proof can easily be made rigorous. $\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$ is the probability that a random natural number modulo $n$ is coprime to $n$; equivalently, it's the probability that a random natural number in $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$ is coprime to $n$. This is a finite set and so there's no need to discuss limits:

the probability that a natural number in this set is divisible by a prime divisor $p$ of $n$ is $\frac{1}{p}$, rigorously; we are just dividing two finite numbers $\frac{n}{p}$ and $n$, and
the probability that a natural number in this set is divisible by two distinct prime divisors $p, q$ of $n$ is $\frac{1}{pq}$. So the events are independent, again rigorously.

And similarly for the entire set $p_1, \dots p_k$ of prime divisors of $n$. In the end this argument ends up being exactly equivalent to the counting proof but I think the conceptual connection to probabilistic independence is nice and can make it easier to remember. The probabilistic argument also naturally suggests the interesting follow-up question of understanding the product $\prod_p \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right)$ (the probability that a random positive integer is not divisible by any primes!), which leads to a proof of the infinitude of the primes (that deduces it from the divergence of the harmonic series! See e.g. Keith Conrad), the Euler product of the zeta function, a heuristic argument for the prime number theorem, etc. etc.
(It is also actually true that all of these statements remain true for natural density, for an arbitrary finite set of primes $p$, but this is unnecessary for the desired result.)

With the thanks of @lulu and @Karl I was able to clear up what I was misunderstanding but basically I had two issues

I was thinking of the probability of any $p$ prime dividing $n$, which is not true it is $p-1$.
I was taking for granted that the probability of a number being divided by two different primes were independent (still true, just needs to be proven).

Lets see how these go:

I only need to consider primes up to $n$, so for example if $$n = \prod_{i = 1}^n p_i^k$$ what this means is that if $q < p$ is coprime with $p$ then we actually have $p^{k}$ of these until $n$, taking all the numbers that are coprime up to $p$ and then extending to the whole $n$ range we get $p^k(p-1)$ (all the multiples up to $p^k$), and when taking favorable/all possible outcomes we will cancel with $\dfrac{1}{p^k}$ giving the probability $\dfrac{1}{p-1}$.

For independence, if $n = pq$ with $p, q$ primes then we have only one value that is divisible by both, thus again taking favorable over total outcomes we have the probability of being divisible by both as $\dfrac{1}{pq}$ but this is the same as the individual probabilities multiplied. Meaning they're independent. This is also valid for any combination of primes and powers we take.



Even passing to the prime factorization of $n$ is overkill. It's really simple: if $p$ is a prime dividing $n$, then the multiples of $p$ less than or equal to $n$ are $p, 2p, 3p, \dots \frac{n}{p} p$, and there are $\frac{n}{p}$ of these. Similarly if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes dividing $n$, etc.
